# Accessing data of notepad

Tags: matlab, notepad

I have notepad data like this:

```
-1 1:0.009 2:-0.056 3:6.009
```

The data is in rows and columns while every row starts with 1 or -1. When I try to access data in matlab, e.g:

```
data=load('*.txt')
X=data(1,:)
```

I will get `-1 1 2 3`  which represent the no. of data point not actual data, rather 0.009 0.056 6.009 which is actual data. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details to make this into an answerable question.

Comment: Smells like an incorrect regex.

Comment: Dude are you talking about code or a find feature.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a simple `load` is to use `fscanf` or `textscan`, as in

```
fid=fopen('accessing_data_of_notepad.txt')
dat = textscan(fid,'%s')
fclose(fid)
```

Your data will be in cell array `dat`. You can modify the format specifier to suit your needs, for instance if you want all of the numbers you can use something like

```
fid=fopen('accessing_data_of_notepad.txt');
dat = textscan(fid,'%d %d:%.3f %d:%.3f %d:%.3f')
fclose(fid);
```

Values `0.009 0.056 6.009`  will be in `dat{3}`, `dat{5}` and `dat{7}`